# Creating a three.js BufferedGeometry directy from its vertices

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry, vertex

I am converting a Java3D app into WebGL using three.js. My first steps is to convert the shapes in my app and display them in my three.js scene.

In Java3D, these shapes are built by revolving a lathe curve around the y-axis. Since I couldn't find a way to use the `THREE.LatheGeometry` with custom rotation, that is not just circular rotation around the y-axis, I decided to try and create the shape directly from its vertices.

In the Java3D code, the vertices are initialized as follows:

```
    double verts[] = surfaceRevolve(xs, ys);
    GeometryInfo geom = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY);
    geom.setCoordinates(verts);
    setGeometry(geom.getGeometryArray());
```

I then took these vertices, and attempted to create a `THREE.BufferGeometry` with them:

```
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    var vertices = new Float32Array(NUM_VERTICES);
    // add the vertices
    geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
```

The issue is that in Java3D, I get a whole, closed off shape. In three.js and WebGL, I get a lot of triangles that somehow make out the shape, but it is not complete. Do I need to add faces? Normals? Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: My shape in Java3D vs. three.js]

Comment: `GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY` from the Java code looks like it is using quads. Did you convert the quads to triangles?

Comment: I did not; I also tried setting the itemSize to 4 in the BufferAttribute but a weird shape appears then.

Comment: WebGL doesn't do QUADs so you'll need to convert them to triangles. I think, but could be wrong, that three.js supports quads but not for BufferGeometry where you're supplying the buffers

Comment: that makes sense, but how do I go about converting these vertices to triangles then?